# Как сделать что бы не приходило письмо на почту когда поле email не заполнено или не коректно написано?

Tags: php, email, спам

```
        <?php
            require "db.php";
            $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $to = '**********@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Нове повідомлення з вашого сайту!';
            $message = "Ім'я:" . $_POST['name'] . "\nВідгук: " . $_POST['otziv'] ."\nE-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nЧас: " . date("d.m.Y - H:i");
            mail($to, $subject, $message);
            if (preg_match('/[a-zA-z0-9]+\@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]+/is',$_POST['email'])){
            $err = "Спасибо за коментар";
            $comments = R::dispense('comments');
            $comments->name = $_POST['name'];
            $comments->otziv = $_POST['otziv'];
            $comments->email = $_POST['email']; 
            $comments->date = date("d M Y");
            $comments->time = date("d.m.Y - H:i");
            R::store($comments);
            header('location: forma.php');      
            }else{
                $err = "Заповніть всі поля!";
            }
            }
        ?>
**Весь код:**

<?php
        require "db.php";
        $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
                $to = '********@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'Нове повідомлення з вашого сайту!';
                $message = "Ім'я:" . $_POST['name'] . "\nВідгук: " . $_POST['otziv'] . "\nE-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nЧас: " . date("d.m.Y - H:i");
                mail($to, $subject, $message);
                if (preg_match('/[a-zA-z0-9]+\@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]+/is',$_POST['email'])){
                    $err = "Спасибо за коментар";
                    $comments = R::dispense('comments');
                    $comments->name = $_POST['name'];
                    $comments->otziv = $_POST['otziv'];
                    $comments->email = $_POST['email'];
                    $comments->date = date("d M Y");
                    $comments->time = date("d.m.Y - H:i");
                    R::store($comments);
                    header('location: forma.php');
                }else{
                    $err = "Заповніть всі поля!";
                }
            } else {
                $err = "Поле e-mail не заполнено!";
            }
        }
        ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Отзывы</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="Your description">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">
        <meta name="author" content="Your name">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){ 

                $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
                    }
                }); 

                $('.scrollup').click(function(){
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
                    return false;
                });

            });
            </script>
            <style>
        .comment .date{
        font-size:10px;
        padding:1px 0;
        position:absolute;
        color:#bbb;
        }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--==============================header=================================-->
    <header id="header">
          <div class="container">
            <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand_"><a href="index.html"><img alt="Grill point" src="img/logo.png"></a></h1>
          </div>
          <div class="menuheader">
              <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top tm_navbar" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Головна</a>

                       </li>
                      <li><a href="foto.html">Портфоліо фото</a></li>
                      <li><a href="video.html">Портфоліо відео</a></li>
                      <li><a href="forma.php">Відгуки</a></li>
                       <li class="active"><a href="#.html">Ціни</a>
                           <ul>
                          <li><img src="img/arrowup.png" alt=""><a href="price_foto.html">фотозйомка</a></li>
                          <li><a href="price_video.html">Відеозйомка</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      <li><a href="blog.html">Блог</a></li>
                      <li><a href="kontakti.html">Контакти</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
          </div>
    </header>
    <div id="content">
        <!--==============================row5=================================-->
        <div class="row_5">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">


                            <h2 class="pad_bot1">Ваші коментарі</h2>

        <div class=tab>
        <table width=100%>
        <form name="f_add_otziv" action="" method="post">
                <tr><td><font face=Helvetica><font size=4px>Ваше ім'я:</font><br></td>
                <td><input name="name" type="text" value="" size="60" id="name"></td></tr>
                <tr><td height=20px><font size=4px>Ваш e-mail:</font></td>
                <td><input name="email" type="text" value="" size="60"></td></tr>
                <tr><td height=20px><font size=4px>Повідомлення:</font></td>
                <td>
                <textarea name="otziv" cols="55" rows="3" wrap="off"></textarea>
                </td></tr>
                <tr><td height=15px></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Відправити"></td></tr>        
                <tr><td height=15px><?= '<div style="color:red">'.$err.'</div>' ?></td></tr>        
                <tr><td height=2px></td></tr>           
           </form>
            </table>
        </div>
    <?php $commen = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `id` DESC") ?>
    <?php while ($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commen)){   
    ?>

    <hr>
    <div class="comment">
            <div class="date" title="Опубліковано: <?= $com['time'] ?>"><?= $com['date']?></div>        
            <br>
            <div class="name"><b><?= $com['name'] ?>:</b></div>
            Коментар:<br>
            <div class="otziv"><p class="m_bot2"><?= $com['otziv'] ?></p></div>
            </div>
    <hr>
    <?php } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footercol">
                    <ul class="social_icons clearfix">
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/photostudioamur/" target=_blank><img src="img/instagram.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li><li><a href="https://xn--80affa3aj0al.xn--80asehdb/#/im?p=u693858804_17474672909153016356" target=_blank><img src="img/telega.png" alt=""></a></li> 

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footerlogo footercol">
                    <a class="smalllogo2 logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo_wite_sm.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footercol">
                    <p class="footerpriv">&copy; 2019 <a class="privacylink" href="index-5.html"></a><!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <a href="#" class="scrollup">Наверх</a>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tm-scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не использовать `mail($to, $subject, $message);`

Дополнение, для автора, ввиду его "хотелок"
Сообщение не будет отправляться при отсутствии данных в поле с именем "email"

```php
<?php
require "db.php";
$headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $to = '********@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Нове повідомлення з вашого сайту!';
        $message = "Ім'я:" . $_POST['name'] . "\nВідгук: " . $_POST['otziv'] . "\nE-mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\nЧас: " . date("d.m.Y - H:i");
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
        if (preg_match('/[a-zA-z0-9]+\@[a-zA-z0-9]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]+/is',$_POST['email'])){
            $err = "Спасибо за коментар";
            $comments = R::dispense('comments');
            $comments->name = $_POST['name'];
            $comments->otziv = $_POST['otziv'];
            $comments->email = $_POST['email'];
            $comments->date = date("d M Y");
            $comments->time = date("d.m.Y - H:i");
            R::store($comments);
            header('location: forma.php');
        }else{
            $err = "Заповніть всі поля!";
        }
    } else {
        $err = "Поле e-mail не заполнено!";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Отзывы</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="Your description">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Your keywords">
    <meta name="author" content="Your name">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                    $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
                }
            });

            $('.scrollup').click(function(){
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style>
        .comment .date{
            font-size:10px;
            padding:1px 0;
            position:absolute;
            color:#bbb;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--==============================header=================================-->
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="navbar-brand navbar-brand_"><a href="index.html"><img alt="Grill point" src="img/logo.png"></a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menuheader">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top tm_navbar" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav sf-menu">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Головна</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="foto.html">Портфоліо фото</a></li>
                    <li><a href="video.html">Портфоліо відео</a></li>
                    <li><a href="forma.php">Відгуки</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#.html">Ціни</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><img src="img/arrowup.png" alt=""><a href="price_foto.html">фотозйомка</a></li>
                            <li><a href="price_video.html">Відеозйомка</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    <li><a href="blog.html">Блог</a></li>
                    <li><a href="kontakti.html">Контакти</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <!--==============================row5=================================-->
    <div class="row_5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


                <h2 class="pad_bot1">Ваші коментарі</h2>

                <div class=tab>
                    <table width=100%>
                        <form name="f_add_otziv" action="" method="post">
                            <tr><td><font face=Helvetica><font size=4px>Ваше ім'я:</font><br></td>
                                <td><input name="name" type="text" value="" size="60" id="name"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td height=20px><font size=4px>Ваш e-mail:</font></td>
                                <td><input name="email" type="text" value="" size="60"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td height=20px><font size=4px>Повідомлення:</font></td>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea name="otziv" cols="55" rows="3" wrap="off"></textarea>
                                </td></tr>
                            <tr><td height=15px></td></tr>
                            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Відправити"></td></tr>
                            <tr><td height=15px><?= '<div style="color:red">'.$err.'</div>' ?></td></tr>
                            <tr><td height=2px></td></tr>
                        </form>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <?php $commen = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `id` DESC") ?>
                <?php while ($com = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commen)){
                    ?>

                    <hr>
                    <div class="comment">
                        <div class="date" title="Опубліковано: <?= $com['time'] ?>"><?= $com['date']?></div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="name"><b><?= $com['name'] ?>:</b></div>
                        Коментар:<br>
                        <div class="otziv"><p class="m_bot2"><?= $com['otziv'] ?></p></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footercol">
                <ul class="social_icons clearfix">
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/photostudioamur/" target=_blank><img src="img/instagram.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li><li><a href="https://xn--80affa3aj0al.xn--80asehdb/#/im?p=u693858804_17474672909153016356" target=_blank><img src="img/telega.png" alt=""></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footerlogo footercol">
                <a class="smalllogo2 logo" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo_wite_sm.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 footercol">
                <p class="footerpriv">&copy; 2019 <a class="privacylink" href="index-5.html"></a><!-- {%FOOTER_LINK} -->
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<a href="#" class="scrollup">Наверх</a>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tm-scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как по другому?

Comment: в php.ini прописать в disable_functions опцию mail
рестарт apache

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: @РостиславМолодецкий поясните, чего конкретно хотите добиться. Вы предоставили скрипт, чтобы не отправлять письмо - удалите данную функцию mail, которая в php отправляет письмо. Чтобы отключить вообще отправку писем - используйте настройки php.ini. Формулируйте свой вопрос конкретнее.

Comment: Как сделать что бы не приходило на почту когда поле не заполнено?

Comment: Когда не заполнено какое поле????

Comment: ..........email

Comment: @РостиславМолодецкий, если хотите чтобы Вам помогли - ставьте задачу конкретней!!! Иначе никто не будет сидеть и разбираться в Вашем коде, и что конкретно Вы теоретически могли иметь ввиду.

Comment: Значит у Вас заполнено поле email. Вы хоть пытаетесь разобраться?
Поясню подробнее. isset($_POST['submit']) -- проверяет нажата ли кнопка submit. Если не нажата, то ничего не проиходит. Далее идёт проверка заполнено ли поле c именем email isset($_POST['email']), если оно НЕ заполнено, то ничего не происходит. Если у Вас отравляется письмо, то ОЧЕВИДНО, что оно заполнено.

Comment: поля пустые, не опубликовуется но приходит на почту

Comment: всё скинул.....

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)